# How can i pass an string parameter to custom repository method?

Tags: ajax, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with AJAX + Rest + Spring boot + MySQL. Request is sucess but response is empty, no matter the format used in the request. In fact, the request payload shows ["customer" : "MyCustomer"] so problem is in controller, i think.

AJAX
function ajax_ciudad(customer) {      // onchange en select box

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/api/ciudades",
    data: JSON.stringify(customer),
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
        }).then(function(data) {
            DO SOMETHING.... 
           });
        });
```

}

CONTROLLER

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class SearchController {
@Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;
    @PostMapping("/api/ciudades")
    public @ResponseBody List<?> getSedes(String customer){

        List<Canal> ciudades = myRepository.findBySede(customer);
        return ciudades;
    }


REPOSITORY
    @Query(value ="SELECT * FROM canal WHERE cliente = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Canal> findBySede(@Param("customer") String customer);
```

... Always return an empty object []

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6QkZ.png)

I have tried several formats for data, i tried getting the Select value using .val() to get the String, using .value to get the html value.... If i put manually a parameter like myRepository.findBySede("MyString") the ajax response has info, but when i pass the value it doesn't work; What i'm doing wrong? Thanks for your help

My entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "canal")
public class Canal { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idcanal", unique = true, nullable = false)
    int id;
    @Column(name = "cliente")
    String cliente;
    @Column(name = "ciudad")
    String ciudad;
    @Column(name = "sede")
    String sede;
    @Column(name = "canal")
    String canal;
    @Column(name = "ip_pe")
    String ip_pe;
    @Column(name = "nombre_pe")
    String nombre_pe;
    @Column(name = "ipwan_pe")
    String ipwan_pe;
    @Column(name = "puerto_pe")
    String puerto_pe    ;
    @Column(name = "ipwan_router")
    String ipwan_router;
    @Column(name = "enrutamiento")
    String enrutamiento;
    *****getters and setters****
     }
```

Comment: Did you debug what is happening in controller? Does repository actually return non-empty collection for given customer?

Comment: Yes, when i put a customer in method i get response with correct data. It seems like problem is mapping argument to the repository method

Comment: Did you try to replace `List<?>` with `List<Canal>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am hoping you have defined your repo correctly and returning correct data based on customer string.

Pass from ajax `"customer"` as `@Param` and Define your controller like this as `@RestController` includes `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody:`

```
@RestController
public class SearchController {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @PostMapping("/api/ciudades")
    public List<Canal> getSedes(@Param("customer") String customer){

        List<Canal> ciudades = myRepository.findBySede(customer);
        return ciudades;
    }
```

Or better way, return ResponseEntity..

```
@RestController
public class SearchController {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @PostMapping("/api/ciudades")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getSedes(@Param("customer") String customer){

        List<Canal> ciudades = myRepository.findBySede(customer);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ciudades , HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Define your method like this in repo:

```
@Repository|
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<Canal, String> 

    @Query(value ="SELECT * FROM canal GROUP BY cliente", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Canal> findByIdcanal(); // works fines

  //I assume here you have canal table and cliente is column in it as you 
   running native query

    @Query(value ="SELECT * FROM canal WHERE cliente = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Canal> findBySede(String customer); // doesn't work

  //OR try this as JPQL if you have Canal is entity and cliente as string type in it.
    @Query(value ="Select c from Canal c WHERE c.cliente = :cliente")
    List<Canal> findBySede(@Param("cliente") String customer); 

   //OR simply have Named query I assume you have Canal and cliente string type

   List<Canal> findByCliente(String customer); 


}
```

**UPDATE** as I checked your native query is fine..

If you want to send customer(string) as @RequestBody in controller then follow below:

1. Create a Class Customer

   ```
   public class Customer {
   private String customer;

   public String getCustomer() {
       return customer;
   }

   public void setCustomer(String customer) {
       this.customer = customer;
   }
   ```

   }
2. handle request as `@RequestBody`

   ```
   @PostMapping("/api/ciudades")
   public ResponseEntity<?> getSedes(@RequestBody Customer customer){

       List<Canal> ciudades = myRepository.findBySede(customer.getCustomer());
       return new ResponseEntity<>(ciudades , HttpStatus.OK);
   }
   ```

Comment: hi @kj007  It seems like problem is mapping argument to the repository method. I did what you said, but i still getting an empty response

Comment: My repository is like this:

Comment: @MocaccinoFan check my updated answer and also if does not work then please show me your Entity class..or if possible share your sample code on github I can surely look into it.

Comment: I just shared entity class. I'll look your answers, thanks

Comment: your native query seems fine, put a debug point in controller and see you are receiving customer value correct as seems from ajax you are not sending it as param..seems sending as body..check my updated answer to handle as request body

Comment: It's working ! The problem was the handle request, i suppose spring make a kind of toString() to the request Object if you don't specify. You are a hero, man, thank you.

Comment: @MocaccinoFan that’s great, if my answer help you to solve the problem, please accept it as answer.

Comment: @MocaccinoFan just one more suggestion as in your entity primary key is int type so in repository use CrudRepository<Canal, Integer> instead is string.